# javascript page redirect with POST method

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I have a website that redirects a user to a external host for payment processing. When the user is returned to my website depending on the results of the payment processing I need to redirect the user to a final webpage with POST method so their order can be completed. I have the code below which works on Chrome and Opera browsers. On Firefox and IE browsers it fails and the user ends up with a blank page. What do I need to modify for this to work on all browsers?

```
var cSecurem = 'https://www.website.com/';

function gotofinalpage(p1,p2) { 
    setLoginCookie('secure');
    var cURL = cSecurem + 'bh/finalpage.r?param1=' + p1 + '&param2=' + p2;
    var myForm = document.createElement("form");
    myForm.method="post" ;
    myForm.action = cURL ;
    myForm.submit() ;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting on IE and Firefox?

Comment: So you're using POST but passing the data via query string???

Comment: The values being in the URL is only with the GET method. The POST method will get the values from the `name` form elements.

Comment: Maybe jQuery's AJAX tools are the answer for the best multibrowser support?

Comment: @Milkmannetje No. This isn't AJAX, and there's no reason the OP shouldn't need to add dependencies to solve simple javascript problems. There's a solution to this problem.

Comment: This is the error I am getting. `The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.`. Based on searches I did online I added `charset='utf-8'` to the Javascript but that does not look to have helped much `<SCRIPT SRC='js/bh/javascriptfilename.js' LANGUAGE='JavaScript' charset='utf-8'></SCRIPT>`

Answer (score 2):

Add the form to dom before submit and try again please:

```
document.body.appendChild(myForm)
```

Edit: Maybe you should try inline dom manipulation. Suppose that you have an empty div whose id is **formDiv**:

```
var el = document.getElementById("formDiv");
el.innerHTML = '<form id="myForm" action="https://www.website.com/bh/finalpage.r" method="post">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="param1" value="' + p1 + '">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="param2" value="' + p2 + '">' +
'</form>';
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

Note: Dont forget to run this code in document ready event. Some browsers may fail otherwise.

Comment: I tried the code below and it did not resolve the problem. Actually after trying this code Opera which was working before stopped working.    `var myForm = document.createElement("form");
  myForm.method="post" ;
  myForm.action = cURL ;
  document.body.appendChild(myForm); 
  myForm.submit() ;`

Comment: I edited my answer with another method worth to try.

Comment: This is the error I am getting. `The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.`. Based on searches I did online I added `charset='utf-8'` to the Javascript but that does not look to have helped much `<SCRIPT SRC='js/bh/javascriptfilename.js' LANGUAGE='JavaScript' charset='utf-8'></SCRIPT>`